# Can't add to $args $_GET value conditionally - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, sorting

In WordPress I have a loop with some $args array, which I want to be able to edit conditionally depending on a $_GET value.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'       => 'property',
  'post_status'     => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page'  => -1,
  'meta_query'      => $meta_query,
  'tax_query'       => $tax_query,
  'fields'          => 'ids',
  'no_found_rows'   => true,
  'post__in'        => $post__in,
  'nopaging'        => true
);
```

When adding to $args array like this:

```
if ( $_GET['prop_sort'] == 'price' ) {
  $args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num';
  $args['order']    = 'ASC';
  $args['meta_key'] = $prefix . 'price';
}
```

Nothing changes, and added to $args stuff gets ignored. However when I put code like this:

```
args = array(
  'post_type'       => 'property',
  'post_status'     => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page'  => -1,
  'meta_query'      => $meta_query,
  'tax_query'       => $tax_query,
  'fields'          => 'ids',
  'no_found_rows'   => true,
  'post__in'        => $post__in,
  'nopaging'        => true
);

$args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num';
$args['order']    = 'ASC';
$args['meta_key'] = $prefix . 'price';
```

Everything works as intended and posts are sorted by price from small to big.
What could be the problem?

EDIT:

Trying to influence query like this:

```
function myplugin_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

  if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'property' ) {
      $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
      $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
      $query->set( 'meta_key', 'sb_price' );
  }

  return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'myplugin_pre_get_posts', 1 );
```

Dones't work either (Undefined index: post_type in ..\functions.php on line 65).

Comment: Can you please add a print_r for your $_GET variable just before the  if ( $_GET['prop_sort'] == 'price' ) {
 ?

Comment: It gives no result. The $args are in the function - zoner_get_map_points_array() - which is called inside a static function - zoner_gmap_ajax_items() - of the class zoner_maps_shortcode. And the zoner_gmap_ajax_items() is hooked inside of init() of the same zoner_maps_shortcode class -   add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv__zoner_get_items_', array(__CLASS__, 'zoner_gmap_ajax_items'));